# Display events between 12:00 AM to 1:00PM

Tags: apex, datetime

I have queried all the events in salesforce in a list now i want to loop through that list . if the startdate of event is between 12:00 AM to 1:00 PM i want to store in separate list ? how can i do it ?

Comment: Can you post whatever you have tried so far

Comment: Could you please share sudo code if you've tried so far ?